# What to use for animation for iPad? SVG? GIF? Other?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, animation

I am making an app for the iPad/iphone and I want to have a star that tinkles every now and then and/or a rocket that shoots up randomly . What would be the best way to do that? Someone told me to use SVG and another told me that GIFs would be just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SVG isn't going to work unless you are displaying the content in a UIWebView, you can either build the views using drawing code and perform the animations with core animation or use images, the first being far more efficient. Check out [Apple's Core Animation Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

UIImageView has a property animationImages which can be an array of UIImages. That'll certainly be lighter than a web view!

Answer (score 0):

UIView animations are pretty elegant, though if you're code-phobic they're probably not for you. Don't let the affine transformation stuff scare you, it's simpler than it looks.